# Зачем нужны краткие прилагательные и краткие причастия

Tags: краткое-прилагательное, краткое-причастие

1. Всегда ли их можно заменить на полные версии?
2. Существуют ли существенные причины, по которым они используются в языке?

К примеру

```
Он был сделанным из металла    
Он был сделан из металла
Он был сделанный из металла
```

тут нет ошибки, хотя звучит непривычно.

Comment: Ещё же есть стилистические ошибки. Третье точно некорректно с точки зрения стилистики. Первое не далеко ушло.